# Trying to create a CMS but having trouble with the login

Tags: php

CMS Tutorial and the stage I'm up to https://youtu.be/QNxU3Qa6QZs?t=1817

When I enter the wrong details it says that they are incorrect like it should but when I enter the correct details it is meant to login like in the video it shows a blank page but mine just refreshes the page and shows the login form again. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out, thanks.

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');
if (isset($SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    ?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

            <br>

            <ol>
                <li><a href="add.php">Add Article</a></li>
                <li><a href="delete.php">Delete Article</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ol>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = 'Incorrect Details!';
            }
        }
    }

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="../index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

            <br> <br>

            <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
                <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?> </small>
                <br> <br>
            <?php } ?>



        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">         
        </form>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You should _always_ care about security. One day you want to do something more with this application or reuse some of it's code. Then you might not think about the security issues, or miss it in some place(s). It's always best to always do it correctly since that also makes you use to writing secure code.

Answer (score 0):

See this on line 6?

```
$SESSION['logged_in']
```

The PHP [super global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) is: `$_SESSION`. Add an underscore there and it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't the question rather be closed as a typo than answered?

Comment: Probably. Just trying to help the guy along.

Comment: OMGGG thank you sooo much...always the little things aye...you have a great eye for typos, thanks again man

Comment: No problem. Turn on error reporting -- you would have known of this issue immediately.

Comment: or use tools like phpstan; they tell you about undeclared variables and wrong parameter calls

Comment: @DominicBurns Please mark this question as accepted if it solved your problem so it does not show up in an unanswered queue.